# How to copy the value of a checkbox field from Vendor Bill to Payments in Odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have created two checkbox fields called "x_studio_dont_generate_pv" in both the Vendor Bill and Payments models in Odoo 15. I want to automatically copy the value of this field from the Vendor Bill to the corresponding field in Payments when the payment is registered in the Vendor Bill.
I have tried using computed fields and related fields, but I'm not getting the desired result. Can someone please provide guidance on the best approach to achieve this requirement?

from odoo import models, fields, api

class AccountPayment(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.payment'

```
x_studio_dont_generate_pv = fields.Boolean(string='Do not Generate PV', compute='_compute_x_studio_dont_generate_pv', store=True)

@api.depends('invoice_ids.x_studio_dont_generate_pv')
def _compute_x_studio_dont_generate_pv(self):
    for payment in self:
        payment.x_studio_dont_generate_pv = invoice_ids.x_studio_dont_generate_pv
```